# Computation of follow set

Tags: grammar

To compute FOLLOW(A) for all non-terminals A, apply the following rules
until nothing can be added to any FOLLOW set.

1. Place $ in FOLLOW(S) , where S is the start symbol, and $ is the input
   right endmarker .
2. If there is a production A -> B, then everything in FIRST(b) except epsilon
   is in FOLLOW(B) .
3. If there is a production A -> aBb, or a production A -> aBb, where
   FIRST(b) contains t, then everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B).
   a,b is actually alpha and beta(sentential form). This is from dragon book.

Now my question is in this case can we take a=epsilon ?
and can b(beta) be 2 non-terminals like XY? (if senetntial then it solud be..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the Dragon book actually says: [See note 1]

1. Place **$** in **FOLLOW(*S*)**.
2. For every production ***A*→α*B*β**, place everything
   in **FIRST(β)** except **ε** into
   **FOLLOW(*B*)**
3. For every production ***A*→α*B*** or
   ***A*→α*B*β** where **FIRST(β)** contains
   **ε**, place **FOLLOW(*A*)** into
   **FOLLOW(*B*)**.

There is a section earlier in the book on "notational conventions" in which it is made clear that a lower-case greek letter like **α** or **β** represents a possibly empty string of grammar symbols. So, yes, **α** could be empty and **β** could be two nonterminals (or any other string of grammar symbols).

---

#### Note:

1. Here I'm using a variant on the formatting suggesting made by @leftroundabout in [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285924/1566221). (The only difference is that I put the formulae in bold.) It's easy to type Greek letters as entities if you don't have a Greek keyboard handy; just use, for example, &alpha; (α) or &beta; (β). For upper-case Greek letters, write the name with an upper-case letter: &Sigma; (Σ). Other useful symbols are arrows: &rarr; (→) and &rArr; (⇒).